# Log in into the same account using several email addresses

Tags: support, user-accounts

I can log into the same account (https://stackoverflow.com/users/7751131/parvin) using:

- My Yahoo email address
- My Google email address,
- Google log in (the red bottom)

Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Stack Exchange platform supports using several login-names/email addresses for the same account - more info can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/edit-credentials).

> Adding additional logins to your account is useful because it provides
>   a way to access your account in case you lose your password. You can
>   choose Google, Facebook, Yahoo!, and other popular OpenID providers;
>   create a new Stack Exchange OpenID by providing your email address and
>   creating a password; or you can manually enter another OpenID address.
>
> Open up your user profile page (if you can't remember how to log in,
>   go here and enter your email) and, on most sites, open the "Edit
>   Profile and Settings" section of your profile, and then click the "My
>   Logins" tab: my logins in new profile page You should see a list of
>   your logins.